# IPC in the same machine...WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, client, ipc

I'm developing a client/server application.
Both are on the same machine, and the communication will be 1-1 so one server one client always.

But I have to make client and server behave like server and client, so any of them can start the "talking" if they need to.
I came with a named pipes solution with WCF (C#) but my question is:
Is there any other better way to do it?
I need to declare 2 named pipes for each client-server communication and maybe there is some kind of limitation on the number of named pipes so I don't know how to get a better approach.

Any sugestions?

Comment: Is it possible to put them in the same process?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, named pipes has no limitation, just your computer resources limit.
And since they work pretty fast and I'm using it in my local machine, it is the best option.
Have my project running and rocking.

Thanks for the suggestion but wasnt that good

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) as it works on most technologies and does exactly what you want. It is very easy to get started and works out of the box!